My Slack bot running a Google virtual machine via Docker is running into issues
I am building a Slack bot running on a virtual environment, but Slack wants me to update my browser.

Here is my Dockerfile:"
# Use a specific selenium/node-chrome base image
FROM selenium/node-chrome:4.10.0

# Set the working directory inside the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

USER seluser

# Install Node.js and npm
RUN sudo apt-get update && \
    sudo apt-get install -y curl software-properties-common && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | sudo bash - && \
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Check Node.js and npm versions
RUN node --version && npm --version

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install npm dependencies
RUN sudo npm install

# Copy the rest of your application
COPY . .
RUN sudo chown -R seluser:seluser /app

# Set environment variable for Chrome
ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome
ENV CHROME_PATH=/usr/bin/google-chrome

# Copy entrypoint script
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sudo chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

# Expose the port your app runs on
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run your app
CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]

And here is how I initialize the driver:
const { Builder, By } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

let options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments('--headless'); // Run headless Chrome
options.addArguments('--no-sandbox'); // Bypass OS security model
options.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage'); // Overcome limited resource problems
options.addArguments('start-maximized'); // Start maximized
options.addArguments('disable-infobars'); // Disabling infobars
options.addArguments('--disable-extensions'); // Disabling extensions
options.addArguments('--disable-software-rasterizer');
options.addArguments('--window-size=1280,720');
options.addArguments('--display=:99');
options.addArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.5735.133 Safari/537.36")

async function initDriver(email, maintainBrowser){
    let driver;

    try {
        driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);   
    }
    return driver;
}

Here are my Chromedriver and Chrome versions:
Google Chrome 114.0.5735.133 
ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90

What can I do to update the version of the browser to get the Slack bot working?
